# Return a group of cells that match a drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to return a group of cells in a pivot table based on a drop down list in another workbook. In this example, When I select "Store 1", I would like if the entire sub table is returned e.g.

MESS 2 4534,
NIGHT 2 4274,
TOOLS 3 8123

I believe this is a sub row yet using function GETPIVOTDATA only likes to return specific values as when referencing the drop down list I can only pull the totals.
Here is my pivot table.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

RAWDATA (not an image):

```
STORE    ID       Category  Sum
Store 1           1 Tools         4050
Store 2           2 Food          4051
Store 3           3 Tools         4052
Store 4           4 Mess          4053
Store 5           5 Random        4054
Store 6           6 Mal           4055
Store 1           7 Night          200
Store 2           8 Releif        4057
Store 3           9 Test           154
Store 4          10 Tools         4059
Store 5          11 Food          4060
Store 6          12 Tools        54665
Store 1          13 Mess           454
Store 2          14 Random          45
Store 3          15 Mal           4064
Store 4          16 Night         4065
Store 5          17 Releif          45
Store 6          18 Test          1451
Store 1          19 Tools         4068
Store 2          20 Food          4069
Store 3          21 Tools           15
Store 4          22 Mess          4071
Store 5          23 Random        4072
Store 6          24 Mal           4073
Store 1          25 Night         4074
Store 2          26 Releif        4075
Store 3          27 Test          4076
Store 4          28 Tools           45
Store 5          29 Food          4078
Store 6          30 Tools           45
Store 1          31 Mess          4080
Store 2          32 Random          42
Store 3          33 Mal            523
Store 4          34 Night          453
Store 5          35 Releif           4
Store 6          36 Test           532
Store 1          37 Tools            5
Store 2          38 Food          4087
Store 3          39 Tools         2425
Store 4          40 Mess             2
Store 5          41 Random          45
Store 6          42 Mal              3
```

Comment: As in the raw data?

Comment: STORE, ID CATEGORY, SUM are the headers. I'm not sure how I would share the raw file with you. But do you have any ideas yet?

Comment: Hey - added the raw. @Mech

Comment: Hey yes - I can do that. But I'm using the data in another workbook. So the drop down list is in another workbook which then pulls the data from the pivot table. (Sory should have explained that)

Comment: I added the RAWDATA from your image, because an image is NOT rawdata....

Comment: @mech its called Dashboard is the workbook and Summary is the worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks for changes in workbook `Dashboard`, worksheet `Summary`, in cell `E3` then changes the value of PivotTable `pTbl` using VBA.

When triggered, the VBA code will

> - clear the filters if they exist
> - filter the data with the contents of `E3`

---

To access VBA:

> - press alt-F11
> - expand Microsoft Excel Objects (left hand side)
> - locate the "Summary" worksheet
>
> [image]

---

Find the name of your PivotTable:

> - click the pivot table
> - click the "PivotTable Analyze" tab
> - on the left, you will see "PivotTable Name:"
> - change `pTbl` (currently "PivotTable6") to this name
>
> [image]

---

You can change the values of `Dashboard`, `Summary`, `E3`, and `pTbl` as needed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("Dashboard")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
    Dim trigRng As Range: Set trigRng = ws.Range("E3")
    Dim pTbl as String

    pTbl = "PivotTable6"
   
    If Not Application.Intersect(trigRng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ws.PivotTables(pTbl).PivotFields("Store").ClearAllFilters
        ws.PivotTables(pTbl).PivotFields("Store").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=trigRng.Value
    End If
End Sub
```